# Modify ack deadline in asynchronous subscriber

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I currently switched to version `0.24.0-beta` of the google-cloud-pubsub library and can't find a way to modify acknowledge deadline of the message. In the previous version there was a `modifyAckDeadline()`, which allowed me to do it. Is it possible in the new version?

To get an idea why I'm trying to it: What I want to achieve is a kind of retry mechanism where messages that failed to process are redelivered in 10 minutes, and acked only after X such unsuccessful retries.

Answer (score 5):

For purposes of keeping the lease on a message because it will take longer to process, the new version of the subscriber library calls modifyAckDeadline in the background for you. As long the message is outstanding, i.e., you haven't called ack() or nack() on the AckReplyConsumer that your MessageReceiver receives with the message, the library itself will call modifyAckDeadline on the message.

Your goal is a little different: you want to use modifyAckDeadline to best-effort prevent message redelivery for a time. If the time you want to wait is always going to be 10 minutes, then the best thing to do is to call [`setMaxAckExtensionPeriod()`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setMaxAckExtensionPeriod-org.threeten.bp.Duration-) with a duration of 10 minutes on the `Subscriber.Builder` when creating your subscriber. Then, when you fail to process a message, just don't ack or nack the message. The client library will continue to modifyAckDeadline for ten minutes, after which the message can be redelivered.

Comment: Thanks, this works great up until there are more than 500 messages in the subscription. When there are 5, the subscriber receives 5 then hangs and doesn't have more to process. When there are 600, the subscriber receives 600 and instead of hanging and waiting, some messages are redelivered immediately, some of them more then once. Each run it's a different number  of messages processed - 840, 1220, 1170, instead of 600.